# Auto Increment Not starting from defined value for multi column primary key

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, composite-primary-key

I've a table where if `client_id` changes then `branch_id` will start from 101. but the auto increment value always starting from 1. when `client_id` changes then `branch_id` starting from 1. The primary concept is implemented, but unable to start the `branch_id` from 101

```
CREATE TABLE `branch_details` (    
 `client_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL,    
 `branch_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
 `branch_code` text COMMENT 'unique',  
 `branch_name` text,  
 PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`,`branch_id`)  
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: 101 or 100001? Bit confused here

Comment: "For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as ...", see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html  (but that does not answer why it will not start at 100001).

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's 101

Comment: If you want to AUTO_INCREMENT `branch_id`, then each pair `(client_id,branch_id)` is always unique by the branch:id. So change the primary key to `PRIMARY KEY (branch_id) `.